# Spring Boot Liquibase doesn't appear to support XML formatted changelog

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

`spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.5`

I have configured the following in my `src/main/resources/application.yml` file:

```yaml
spring:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: prod
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: ${DB_URL}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
```

Additionally, the following resource exists in the project repository:

```
src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

I also have the following configured in `src/test/resources/application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username: sa
    password: sa
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

When I try to build this project the build fails with the following error message:

> Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found at 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'

Is there some way to configure spring boot to allow an xml based liquibase changelog file? If so, what am I missing? Or does it only support the yaml format?

Answer (score 2):

Your configurations seems valid, but some configuration still points to `classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml` (based by on provided error message)

If there is no some typo, than may be you should look for this property in some other configuration (.properties files, command line arguments and other, [see doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.5/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) for all possible ways)

Comment: You could alternatively create a "src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml" file that simply references the existing "src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml"